# Dart: How to create one extension for any type

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

Instead of creating an extension for every type (in dart) I would like to create one extension that returns the type that was extended.

It's easier to describe with a simple example:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  final T value;

  const Foo(this.value);
}

extension on dynamic {
  Foo get foo => Foo(this);
}

final doubleTest = 0.0.foo;
final stringTest = "hello".foo;

print(doubleTest.runtimeType);
print(stringTest.runtimeType);


// Desirable output:
Foo<double>
Foo<String>

// Actual output:
Foo<dynamic>
Foo<dynamic>
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out myself. Not much to explain. It's as simple as:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  final T value;

  const Foo(this.value);
}

extension FooExtension<T> on T {
  Foo<T> get foo => Foo<T>(this);
}
```

Now running

```dart
final doubleTest = 0.0.foo;
final stringTest = "hello".foo;

print(doubleTest.runtimeType);
print(stringTest.runtimeType);
```

Outputs:

```dart
Foo<double>
Foo<String>
```

Comment: You should name your extension though, like `extension MyExtension<T> on T { ... }`

Comment: The name permits it to be imported with a prefix, similar to importing globals with a prefix.  This will create namespaced additional instance methods.